# Index Unique Combinations in Power Query

Tags: indexing, count, powerquery, group

I am trying to aggregate and index by two columns in Power Query.  For every number in Column A I want to aggregate the numbers in column B and only count up the index when it changes.  Index resets when A ticks over to a new value

| A | B | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 1 |
| 123 | 456 | 1 |
| 123 | 457 | 2 |
| 123 | 458 | 3 |
| 124 | 459 | 1 |
| 124 | 459 | 1 |
| 124 | 460 | 2 |
| 124 | 460 | 2 |

The scenario is A is a Transport number and B is a Customer Account reference - the Count is therefore a stop sequence for the vehicle.

I want to do this in Power Query since it is part of a daily transformation of data out of one system to be uploaded into another system to be done by the user

I have tried the Transfer > Group by and have managed to get an index on A counting up and resetting when a new value appears in A using https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/numbering-grouped-data-power-query but I am struggling with how to do it only iterating up when a new B is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

It sums B by A, and indexes each B by A, resettting each time A resets

Group on A, sum B, add operation for all rows, then replace **each _** with **each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)** and expand

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"Count", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A"}, {{"BSum", each List.Sum([B]), type nullable number}, {"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"B", "Count", "Index"}, {"B", "Count", "Index"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

**Alternate Version**

It sums B by A, and indexes each A

Group on A, sum B, add operation all rows. Then add index. Expand

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"Count", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A"}, {{"BSum", each List.Sum([B]), type nullable number}, {"data", each _, type table }}),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index1", "data", {"B", "Count"}, {"B", "Count"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

When I am trying this using your exact code in both cases I get the Count column with null inside.  Can you point where I am going wrong?

Comment: I am following up until getting the Count in

Currently have A, BSum, B, Index all in, but the last step is confusing me.  When I expand the table in the last step, I can't get it to both show B and Count C

Comment: Using the sample data, edit your question to post your code pasted from home ... advanced editor ...   I added a step for change type if that helps, not sure what types you were using

Comment: now copy and pasting your code gives an error Expression.Error: The column 'Count' of the table wasn't found.  Will edit question to show

Comment: Show your sample data and code you are using.  The sample data has column Count so not sure how it could not be there   My code works perfectly with the sample data